# Jackson writeValueAsString() throws JsonMappingException periodically

Tags: java, jackson

seeing periodic exceptions thrown when calling `writeValueAsString()` to marshall to JSON periodically...but, they always work when retried...

This is thrown by Jackson's API (v2.7.5) when parsing/marshaling a (non null) Java Date value to JSON...

here is our setup that is defined class level and reused across multiple threads/requests

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

and the full stack trace...

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) (through reference chain: MyIndex["createdAt"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:186)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:640)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:632)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2811)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2268)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is a duplicate, @JarrodRoberson. He's got some object which he serializing to JSON using Jackson. Jackson is throwing the exception, not his code, so where is he going to check his indices?

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is thread safe on serializing. Is your POJO shared between threads?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Jackson, Ben? It looks like some ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions have been fixed in the past...

Comment: the class with the ObjectMapper reference is used by multiple threads...also, using Jackson 2.3.0...I'll try again with 2.7.5...thx

Comment: no luck, getting the same error with 2.7.5...randomly

Comment: I added a manual retry and writeValueAsString() works every time with the same data immediately after throwing that exception...sure seems like a threading/race condition to me.  I'm going to make the shared instance ThreadLocal next to see if that solves it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

further testing showed the root cause was non thread safe use of SimpleDateFormatter in the getter method of the class that Jackson was serializing...so Jackson is off the hook (and I'm back on it)...

changed to use a `ThreadLocal<DateFormat>` and all is well...

```
public class ThreadLocalDateFormat extends ThreadLocal<DateFormat>
{
    private String dateFormat;

    public ThreadLocalDateFormat(String dateFormat)
    {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue()
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    }
}
```

thanks for the help...