# Jackson writeValueAsString() throws JsonMappingException randomly

Tags: java, jackson-databind

Getting random 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException' during serialization of an object. The caused by exception is 'Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2'

When re-running with same object again multiple times it passes properly without any exception.

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Index: 3, Size: 2 (through reference chain: com.model.DefOperation["arguments"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.DefOperation["arguments"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.model.Def["input"]->com.model.DefInput["filter"]->com.model.DefInputExpression["DefInput"]->com.model.DefInput["filter"]->com.model.OperationExpression["operation"]->com.model.ProducerOperation["arguments"]->java.util.ArrayList[3])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:210)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:492)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:119)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:492)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:119)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:492)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2210)
    at com.model.Executor.copyDatasetDefOperation(Executor.java:235)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:84)
    ... 44 more
```

Have not used any custom serializer

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String op = mapper.writeValueAsString(operation);
```

jackson-databind version is 2.4.5

Checked the similar issue: [Jackson writeValueAsString() throws JsonMappingException periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064283/jackson-writevalueasstring-throws-jsonmappingexception-periodically)
But there are no date/timestamp attributes in our input object.

Comment: Is there a reason your Jackson version is so old? The latest version is 2.13.1. If you update the version, make sure that all Jackson dependencies use the same version, otherwise you may get (other) errors.

Comment: Changing the jackson version is the last option we have kept as this has a bigger impact for us right now. All the related spring, spark versions will also be impacted.

Comment: Try updating at least to version 2.4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will resolve your specific problem, but whether it may or may or may not it might simplify your serializing to Json issue. There is an open source library called MgntUtils that has a class JsonUtils with methods:

```
writeObjectToJsonString(java.lang.Object object)
```

and

```
readObjectFromJsonString(java.lang.String jsonString, java.lang.Class<T> type)
```

It uses jackson library under the hood anyway. So those are just a wrapper methods for simplifying use for standard and simple cases which usually is the majority of uses. Here is the JavaDoc for the [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class. The library could be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). Also, it uses newer version of jackson - 2.12.3